# MonoTouch: ESSession for external accessories

Tags: xamarin.ios, external-accessory

I am porting coding from Objective C to MonoTouch to use an external accessory.  It is super basic coding, however when I create The EASession and try to use the InputStream or OutputStream, they are both NULL.  I have used it in Objective-C so I know this should not happen.

I am able to repeatedly connect/disconnect the device and detect it.  Now I just can't seem to read the data from the device because of this null issue.  Below is my coding:

session = new EASession(acc, "com.idtechproducts.reader");

session.OutputStream.Delegate = streamDel; // Crashed saying OutputStream is null

session.OutputStream.Schedule (NSRunLoop.Current , "NSDefaultRunLoopMode");

session.OutputStream.Open ();

Comment: Perhaps the "accessory" parameter is wrong, or the protocol string?

Comment: I know acc is correct, and pretty sure i copied the protocol but I can easily just take that from acc itself.  I will test in a little bit and update.  It's weird though, I cannot find a single example of using external accessories anywhere for monotouch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to list the external accessories you're going to use in your
Info.plist.

There is some documentation on this on apple's site:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009502

Here is a screenshot of how to set this value in Info.plist:
http://screencast.com/t/AYmOWjf8wkL

Comment: did that last week.  It helped get ride of the error, but still couldnt get the data.  Thanks!

Comment: I ended up just making a call to a Objective-C class I built

Comment: Anthony, could you tell us how you solved your problem? By any change are you implemented the iSmart SDK from idtechproducts in Monotouch? (smartcard reader). I am struggling with the .a to get it compiled; he's giving errors on the ARM7 methods missing.

Comment: Adding the protocol doesn't help